# How Can I Publish a KMZ File

Tags: kmz

I developed a KMZ file that includes all of the hiking trails in the Wind River Range.  How can I publish the information so members of the general public can view and download the file?  I don't want to host the information on my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to share your KML/KMZ file with the general public is to upload it to the Google Earth Community (GEC). Details of the community and its origin are discussed [here](https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/04/the-new-google-earth-community.html).

http://googleearthcommunity.proboards.com/

Note you must register first then you can post your KMZ with a description of it and optionally with some screen shots. You can browse the various categories and post to the most relevant category. The most general category is the "Earth" category.